# Can't access a sub-query's attributes in a Django template. I can print out each item's name though

Tags: python, django

In this view, I'm passing it the user's favorite albums and songs:

```
@login_required
def my_favorites(request):
    fav_albums = request.user.album_set.all()
    fav_songs = request.user.song_set.all()
    return  render(request, "billyjoel/my_favorites.html", {"fav_albums": fav_albums, "fav_songs" : fav_songs})
```

It's basically the "my account" page in my project.

I'm iterating through each of the songs ("fav_songs"), and then, for each song, iterating through all albums on which that song exists.

```
{% if  fav_songs.count > 0 %}

  ...

  {% for  song in fav_songs %}  <!-- No colon after "fav_songs" -->

     ...

           {% for  albumsong in song.albums.all %}
              <BR/><I>Number {{ albumsong.sequence_num }} on 
              {#<A HREF="{% url 'album_detail' albumsong.id %}">#}{{ albumsong.name }}</A></I>
           {% endfor %}
```

But while it's printing the correct *number* of albums, the `name` and `id` and `sequence_num` are all the empty-string. (This is why the url is commented out)

[image: screenshot]

I noticed if I pre-pend `{{ albumsong }}` to it, the album's *name* prints out, but I'm not sure how to tell what kind of object it really is, given the limited Python available in Django templates.

How do I access the album's properties, and are there any template tags that would help me diagnose this?

(I'm noticing this is similar to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232741/how-to-display-value-of-a-field-in-a-linked-table-in-a-django-template) I asked a couple weeks ago, but I'm not sure if it's connected yet.)

---

models.py:

```
from  django.db import models
from  django.contrib.auth.models import User
from  time import time

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return  "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace(".", "_"), filename)


class Album(models.Model):
    OFFICIALITY = (
        ('J', 'Major studio release'),
        ('I', 'Non-major official release'),
        ('U', 'Unofficial'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('release date')
    officiality = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=OFFICIALITY)
    is_concert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    main_info_url = models.URLField(blank=False)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, null=True)

    #virtual field to skip over the through table.
    songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", through="AlbumSong")

    users_favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User')

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.title

    class Meta:
        #Default ordering is by release date, ascending.
        ordering = ['pub_date']


class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", null=True, blank=True)
    length_seconds = models.IntegerField()
    lyrics_url = models.URLField(default="", blank=True, null=True)
    albums = models.ManyToManyField("Album", through="AlbumSong")

    users_favorited_by = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def get_length_desc_from_seconds(self):
        if(self.length_seconds == -1):
            return  "-1"
        m, s = divmod(self.length_seconds, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        if(h):
            return  "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
        else:
            return  "%d:%02d" % (m, s)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name

class AlbumSong(models.Model):
    song = models.ForeignKey(Song)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    sequence_num = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'sequence_num',)
        unique_together = ('album', 'song',)

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.album) + ": " + str(self.sequence_num) + ": " + str(self.song)
```

my_favorites.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bj_filters %}
{% block title %}My Favorites{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<H1>Billy Joel Album Browser: Favorite albums and songs for user {{ user. }} </H1>

<H1>Albums</H1>

{% if  fav_albums.count > 0 %}

  <TABLE ALIGN="center" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4" BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE"><TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="middle">
     <TD><B><U>Title</U></B><BR><I><FONT SIZE="-1">(click a title to view its song list)</FONT></I></TD>
     <TD><B><U>Released</U></B></TD>
     <TD>Officiality</TD>
     <TD>Concert</TD>
     <TD>Wiki</TD>
     <TD>Favorite?</TD>
  {% for  album in fav_albums %} <!-- No colon after "fav_albums" -->
  </TR><TR>
     <TD VALIGN="top">
        {% if  album.thumbnail %}
           <img src="/static/{{ album.thumbnail }}" width="25"/>
        {% else %}
           <img src="/static/images/white_block.jpg" width="25"/>
        {% endif %}
        &nbsp; <a href="/albums/get/{{ album.id }}{{ url_params }}">{{ album.title }}</a>
        {% if  album.description %}
           <BR/><FONT SIZE="-1"><I>{{ album.description|truncatewords:10 }}</I></FONT>
        {% endif %}
     <TD>{{ album.pub_date|date:"m/y" }}</TD>
     <TD><IMG SRC="/static/images/{{ album.officiality|multival_to_str:"J,I,U->major,minor,unofficial,broken_image"}}.jpg" height="20"/></TD>
     <TD>{{ album.is_concert|yesno:"Yes,No" }}</TD>
     <TD><A HREF="{{ album.main_info_url }}">Wiki</A></TD>
     <TD><A HREF="{% url 'toggle_album_like_go_to_favs' album.id %}"><I>unfavorite</I></A></TD>
  {% endfor %}
  </TR></TABLE>
{% else %}
  <P><I>You have no favorite albums.</I></P>
{% endif %}

  <H2>Songs</H2>

{% if  fav_songs.count > 0 %}
  <TABLE ALIGN="center" WIDTH="100%" BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4" BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE"><TR ALIGN="center" VALIGN="middle"><TR>
     <TD><B><U>Len</U></B></TD>
     <TD><B><U>Name</U></B></TD>
     <TD><B><U>Lyrics</U></B></TD>
  </TR>
  {% for  song in fav_songs %}  <!-- No colon after "fav_songs" -->
     <TR>
        <TD>{% if  song.get_length_desc_from_seconds == "-1" %}
              <I>n/a</I>
           {% else %}
              {{ song.get_length_desc_from_seconds }}
           {% endif %}
        </TD>
        <TD>{{ song.name }}
           {% if  song.description %}
              <BR/><FONT SIZE="-1"><I>{{ song.description|truncatewords:50 }}</I></FONT>
           {% endif %}
           {% for  albumsong in song.albums.all %}
              <BR/><I>Number {{ albumsong.sequence_num }} on {#<A HREF="{% url 'album_detail' albumsong.id %}">#}{{ albumsong.name }}</A></I>
           {% endfor %}
        </TD>
        <TD>
           {% if  song.lyrics_url %}
              <A HREF="{{ song.lyrics_url }}">Lyrics</A> (direct link)
           {% else %}
              <A HREF="https://www.google.com/webhp?q=#q=site:lyrics.wikia.com+billy+joel+{{ song.name|urlencode }}">Lyrics</A> (search)
           {% endif %}
        </TD>
     </TR>
  {% endfor %}
  </TABLE>
{% else %}
  <P><I>You have no favorite songs.</I></P>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. This

```
{% for  albumsong in song.albums.all %}
    <BR/><I>#{{ albumsong.sequence_num }} on 
    <A HREF="{% url 'album_detail' albumsong.id %}">{{ albumsong.name }}</A></I>
{% endfor %}
```

needs to be changed to this

```
{% for  albumsong in song.albumsong_set.all %}
    <BR/><I>#{{ albumsong.sequence_num }} on
    <A HREF="{% url 'album_detail' albumsong.album.id %}">{{ albumsong.album.title }}</A></I>
{% endfor %}
```

I wish there were diagnostic error messages to help figure this kind of stuff out, instead of just printing empty strings.